# How to use Firebase Cloud FireStore Database in a Next JS project. How to initialize it correctly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

On a firebase.js file I am doing this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENTID
};

export function firebaseDB() {
  // Initialize Firebase
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // firebase.analytics();
  }
  return firebase;
}
```

Then, on pages/index.js I am using the getInitialProps:

```
App.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const firebaseDatabase = await firebaseDB();
  const db = firebaseDatabase.firestore();

  let result;

  db.collection("users")
    .add({
      first: "Ada",
      last: "Lovelace",
      born: 1815
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      result = { docs: docRef };
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      result = { error: error };
    });

    return result
};
```

I am assuming that because of the asynchronous nature I am returning the result variable undefined and getting this error:

```
"App.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object. But found "undefined" instead.
```

So, I am not happy with the way I am configuring this...can someone throw some light?

Comment: What's happening right now with you code is every time you refresh the page and getInitialProps is called, you are creating an Ada Lovelace entry. Is this what you really wanna do for this?

Comment: Hi Edria, no not really, thanks for pointing that out, removing that test to add a new firebase doc, I simply want to know what's the best way to initialize it at the top  of our components tree so that it can be used. What's the best way to initialize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of the ways I can think of:

1. Create an HOC for it and wrap the page components that will be using it. (https://medium.com/@uvictor/simple-firebase-authentication-with-next-js-using-hoc-higher-order-components-8e8931d25cfa)
2. Initialise it in the Root component and pass the DB ref to the children. For example, in your Root component, you declare your routes there. What you wanna do is pass the DB ref to each of the components under it. Though this might be problematic when you wanna do SSR. Not sure how would this play out.
3. If only a single page will be using Firebase (happened to me a couple of times), just do it like what you are doing right now.
4. If you are thinking of using Redux, you might want to initialise firebase and bind it to the store (https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase)

My suggestion is, try not to overcomplicate it. Do what works for you.

Comment: Hi, @Edrian thanks for your thoughts. It's actually the first time I use Next Js and I still have to read better the docs and try out things, you probably say not to pass it as ref since I'm doing SSR probably because it's better to optimize each page/component and that might create performance issues I think?

Comment: For this app I'm building I want to use Firebase FireStore for CRUD operations of the users that would register in the website, I would use Firebase Cloud Storage to save their uploaded docs, so I know eventually I'll need a form page where I can upload the new account, and like a dashboard account with settings, etc. Again, I really appreciate your help

Comment: No worries man. Best of luck to you and your app. If you are going to use it with NextJS, I would suggest doing the Saga way or the HOC way.